# When are child views added to Layout/ViewGroup from XML

Tags: android-layout, android

My question is :
I want to know when does a xLayout (or ViewGroup in general) add a child view from XML ? And by "when" I mean at what point of code, in what "pass" of the "traversal" of the UI toolkit ? 
Which method of xLayout or ViewGroup should I override ?

I have done my homework : I have watched the ["Writing Custom Views For Android"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYtB6mlu7vA) presented (by Adam Powell and Romain Guy) in the last Google I/O and I have read Adam Powell comments on this Google+ [post](https://plus.google.com/115089607132986274709/posts/cT1EuBbxEgN).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Looking for the exact point in Android's source code where children are added.

We can look at what `setContentView(R.layout.some_id)` is doing under the hood.

`setContentView(int)` calls `PhoneWindow#setContentView(int)` - `PhoneWindow`[Link](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java) is a concrete inplementation of `Window`:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    if (mContentParent == null) {
        installDecor();
    } else {
        mContentParent.removeAllViews();
    }
    mLayoutInflater.inflate(layoutResID, mContentParent);
    final Callback cb = getCallback();
    if (cb != null && !isDestroyed()) {
        cb.onContentChanged();
    }
}
```

The method `LayoutInflater#inflate(layoutResID, mContentParent)`  eventually calls `ViewGroup#addView(View, LayoutParams)` on `mContentParent`. In between, child views

> I want to know what happens exactly after I set content view to an XML file that contains a custom view. Afer the constructor there has to be a part in the code where the custom view "parse/read/inflate/convert" XML-declared child views to actual views ! (comment by JohnTube)

Ambiquity: From JohnTube's comment, it seems he is more interested in knowing how a custom view is *inflated*. To know this, we will have to look at the workings of `LayoutInflater`[Link](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java).

So, the answer to `Which method of xLayout or ViewGroup should I override ?` is `ViewGroup#addView(View, LayoutParams)`. Note that, at this point, the inflation of all regular/custom Views has already taken place.

Inflation of custom views:

The following method in `LayoutInflater` is where the `addView(View, LayoutParams)` is called on the parent/root:

Note: The call `mLayoutInflater.inflate(layoutResID, mContentParent);` in `PhoneWindow#setContentView(int)` chains to this. Here `mContentParent` is the `DecorView`: the view that's accessible through `getWindow().getDecorView()`.

```
// Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified XML node.
public View inflate(XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)

// Recursive method used to descend down the xml hierarchy and instantiate views,     
// instantiate their children, and then call onFinishInflate().
void rInflate(XmlPullParser parser, View parent, final AttributeSet attrs,
       boolean finishInflate) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
```

The call of interest in this method(and in the recursive `rInflate(XmlPullParser, View, AttributeSet, boolean)`) is:

```
temp = createViewFromTag(root, name, attrs);
```

Let's see what `createViewFromTag(...)` is doing:

```
View createViewFromTag(View parent, String name, AttributeSet attrs) {
    ....
    ....
    if (view == null) {
        if (-1 == name.indexOf('.')) {
            view = onCreateView(parent, name, attrs);
        } else {
            view = createView(name, null, attrs);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

**The `period(.)` decides whether `onCreateView(...)` or `createView(...)` is called.**

Why this check? Because a `View` defined in `android.view`, `android.widget` or `android.webkit` package is accessed through its class name. For example:

```
android.widget: Button, TextView etc.

android.view: ViewStub. SurfaceView, TextureView etc.

android.webkit: WebView
```

When these views are encountered, `onCreateView(parent, name, attrs)` is called. This method actually chains to `createView(...)`:

```
protected View onCreateView(String name, AttributeSet attrs) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    return createView(name, "android.view.", attrs);
}
```

This would deal with `SurfaceView`, `TextureView` and other views defined in `android.view` package. If you are interested in knowing how `TextView, Button etc.` are dealt with, look at `PhoneLayoutInflater`[Link](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneLayoutInflater.java) - it extends `LayoutInflater` and overrides `onCreateView(...)` to check if `android.widget` and `android.webkit` are the intended package names. In fact, the call `getLayoutInflater()` gets you an instance of `PhoneLayoutInflater`. This is why *if you were to subclass `LayoutInflater`, you couldn't even inflate the simplest of layouts - because `LayoutInflater` can only deal with views from `android.view` package*.

Anyway, I digress. This extra bit happens for regular Views - which don't have a `period(.)` in their definition. Custom views *do* have a period in their names - `com.my.package.CustomView`. *This is how the `LayoutInflater` distinguishes between the two*.

So, in case of a regular view(say, Button), a `prefix` such as `android.widget` will be passed as the second argument - for custom views, this will be `null`. The `prefix` is then used along with the `name` to obtain the constructor for that particular view's class. Custom views don't need this because their `name` is already fully qualified. I guess this has been done for convenience. Else, you would have been defining your layouts in this way:

```
<android.widget.LinearLayout
    ...
    ... />
```

(Its legal though...)

Also, this is why views coming from a support library (eg. <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.../>) have to use fully qualified names.

By the way, if you did want to write your layouts as:

```
<MyCustomView ../>
```

all you have to do is to extend LayoutInflater and add your package name `com.my.package.` to the list of strings that are checked during inflation. Check `PhoneLayoutInflater` for help with this.

Let's see what happens in the final stage for both custom and regular views - `createView(...)`:

```
public final View createView(String name, String prefix, AttributeSet attrs)
                            throws ClassNotFoundException, InflateException {

    // Try looking for the constructor in cache
    Constructor<? extends View> constructor = sConstructorMap.get(name);
    Class<? extends View> clazz = null;

    try {
        if (constructor == null) {
            // Class not found in the cache, see if it's real, and try to add it
            clazz = mContext.getClassLoader().loadClass(
                 prefix != null ? (prefix + name) : name).asSubclass(View.class);
            ....
            // Get constructor   
            constructor = clazz.getConstructor(mConstructorSignature);
            sConstructorMap.put(name, constructor);
        } else {
            ....
        }

        Object[] args = mConstructorArgs;
        args[1] = attrs;

        // Obtain an instance
        final View view = constructor.newInstance(args);
        ....

        // We finally have a view!
        return view;
    }
    // A bunch of catch blocks: 
        - if the only constructor defined is `CustomView(Context)` - NoSuchMethodException
        - if `com.my.package.CustomView` doesn't extend View - ClassCastException
        - if `com.my.package.CustomView` is not found - ClassNotFoundException

    // All these catch blocks throw the often seen `InflateException`.
}
```

... a `View` is born.

Comment: Great answer! I was looking for usages of `addView(View)`, but did not find anything relevant. The reference to `rInflate` in `LayoutInflater` is a big help! The right call I was looking for was `addView(View, int, LayoutParams)`.

Comment: @NiekHaarman Thanks, Niek. `addView(View, int, LayoutParams)` is indeed the right call. All other overloaded `addView` methods chain down to it.

Answer (score 8):

If you're talking about a ViewGroup defined in XML, it's children are added when the view is inflated. This can be when you inflate explicitly with a `LayoutInflater` or when you set the content view of an activity. (There are probably a few other times as well, particularly if you are using stub views.)

If you want to add the children yourself to a `ViewGroup` that is not inflated, you can do that in the view's constructor.

EDIT: If you want to see how the children are added when a view is inflated, this occurs in the call to `LayoutInflater.inflate(XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)`. The source for `android.view.LayoutInflater` is included in the Android SDK distributions; on-line versions can be found in many places ([here at GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#LayoutInflater.inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%2Cboolean%29), for instance). This method ends up being called when, for instance, you call `setContentView(int)` for an `Activity` or when you explicitly inflate a layout resource.

The children are actually added in the call to `rInflate(parser, root, attrs, false);` ("recursive inflate"), which might be called from a couple of different places in the `inflate()` method, depending on what the inflater found as the root tag. You can trace through the code logic yourself. An interesting point is that a child is not added to its parent until its own children have been recursively inflated and added to it.

The other interesting method, used by both `inflate` and `rInflate`, is `createViewFromTag`. This might rely on an installable `LayoutInflater.Factory` (or `.Factory2` object) to create the view, or may end up calling `createView`. There you can see how the call to the view's two-argument constructor (`(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`) is made.