# Is it possible for a custom ViewGroup to "deflate" its layout and inflate another?

Tags: android, layout-inflater, viewgroup

I have a custom ViewGroup:

```
public class GuiContact extends RelativeLayout {
    private ViewGroup content
    ...

    public void onCreate() {
        content = (ViewGroup) View.inflate(context, R.layout.contact, this);
        ...
```

This component has a state-machine to manage its behaviour.  I now realise that this component would be far easier to manage if it had a layour-per-state.

Is there a way of reversing `View.inflate` and calling it again with a different XML layout, on each state-machine change?

Answer (score 2):

In your Activity where you are inflating your viewGroup Try this

```
((ViewGroup) content.getParent()).removeView(content);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's what I was trying to avoid - I would like the `GuiContact` to be able to change its own layout without involving the parent.

Comment: Are you trying to remove only the child views inside the viewgroup?

Comment: I'm not sure how the nesting works in Android - I'm trying to change the layout of the `GuiContact`.  Is the `content`/`contact.xml` which I've inflated a *child* of `GuiContact` or a *part* of `GuiContact`?

Comment: All views added to your viewGroup is considered child of the viewGroup. If you want to remove all child inside your viewGroup you can do it with `yourViewGroup.removeAllView()`  please read this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17334152/6414107)

Comment: So the answer is that there is no reverse of `View.inflate`?  If you want to use a different layout for a `View`, you need to remove the old `View` and add a new instance which inflates a different layout?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
yourViewGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
yourotherrecycleview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: So this adds a layer of UI, which contains all the possible child UIs, of which we just chose one for it to show at a time?